# How to describe the field extension?

Tags: extension-field

Consider the circle with radius $2\sqrt{2}$ centered at the origin and the line joining the points $\left(\frac{1}{2}, 0\right)$, $(4\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2})$. The points of intersection of the line and circle have coordinates which lie in a field extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. Give a precise description of this field extension.

Comment: First you must find the points of intersection!

Comment: The solutions look *horrible*: [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%2By%5E2%3D8,+det%5B%5Bx,y,1%5D,%5B1%2F2,0,1%5D,%5B4sqrt(2),sqrt(2),1%5D%5D%3D0).

Comment: So you solve for the points of intersection and find they are products/sums of rationals and $\sqrt2$ and $\sqrt{121-16\sqrt2}$. So what field extension is needed to accommodate these two values?

Comment: How do you find out the intersection point. I calculate x = $\frac{4\pm \sqrt{136982-32992\sqrt{2}}}{129-16\sqrt{12}}$ and I'm stuck.